# Will changing disks in raid1 damage existing data?

Tags: raid

I created a testing Linux install on a hard drive. At the time I set my server without raid.
I now have two brand new hard drives which I have put into my server and configured as raid 1.
I then installed the same system on these new hard drives.
My question is that if I remove both the new hard drives and put the old one back in will the raid configuration affect the data on my backup/test drive in any way?
I know this seems like a silly question but better safe than sorry

Comment: What controller are you using? If you connect without the controller involved it's fine.

Comment: @Nathan C. The server is a Dell Poweredge R300. The spec sheet lists (PERC 6/E,SAS 6/iR,SAS 5). I think the server is using SAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAID1 is mirror, you should be able to swap any of those drives and let RAID controller rebuild it, it's safe and you should not damage any existing data, however you can always make another temporary backup just in case)

Comment: So if I just take out the new hard drives and put in the old one with no hard drive in the second slot the raid controller will just leave it alone and boot without trying to rebuild or anything?